# Symfony Session Last Request Time

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

Is it possible to make an action (more specifically 'ajax/heartbeat') not update last request time for the session ?

It is used for fetching notifications etc, so it shouldn't update timeout on sessions or they will never expire.

If the user is doing stuff on the page (onmousemove) I set `update=true` else `update=false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you will have to hook into the User lib of Symfony.

`lastRequest` is updated during the initialization of the User lib (ie: [inside `sfBasicSecurityUser`](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/branches/1.4/lib/user/sfBasicSecurityUser.class.php#L230)).

Inside your `app/[appname]/lib/myUser.class.php`, extends this `initialize` function to not set the request time. Something ugly like that:

```
public function initialize(sfEventDispatcher $dispatcher, sfStorage $storage, $options = array())
{
  $lastRequest = $this->getLastRequestTime();

  parent::initialize($dispatcher, $storage, $options);

  if (condition)
  {
    $this->lastRequest = $lastRequest;
  }
}
```

The only things you need to find is, how to catch the module/action from the myUser lib and then place it in `condition`.

Comment: Thx, tho I ended up doing it with filters :)

Comment: I thinking about telling you to check filters too :)